# REGEXP_SUBSTR Remove All Chars after the Match

Tags: oracle, db2

I am trying to extract Work Weeks from user comments, user comments might be like

"Something WW15 Target Complete"

"WW12.3 Good to Go"

Currently my script is grabbing the match but also everything after it,

**Result = WW12.3 Good to Go**

**Ideal Result would be just the WW12.3 part.**

I need to do a course and watch demos on REGEXP but thats for another day unfortunately.

```
SELECT 
  BATCH, OPERATOR, COMMENTS, TXN_DATE
 ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENTS,'WW[^;]+') as ETA
FROM F_LOTCOMMENTHIST
```

I have also tried doing this to remove everything after a space but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT 
  BATCH, OPERATOR, COMMENTS, TXN_DATE
 ,REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENTS,'WW[^;]+'),' [^;]+','') as ETA
FROM F_LOTCOMMENTHIST
```

I understand that I am probably using the wrong pattern string but I just cant figure out what I need when looking at example tables like:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php

Comment: Only tag the DBMS you're really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using an online tester of regular expressions to learn using them.

For example this one: https://regexr.com/5p0m6

You can type your expression and text and you'll see directly the behaviour. Take a look at the cheatsheet and explain section.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do? Oracle, though, I don't know db2.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Something WW15 Target Complete' from dual union all
  3     select 'WW12.3 Good to Go'              from dual union all
  4     select 'What is that WW1.2'             from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7         regexp_substr(col, 'WW(\w+)?((\.)?(\d+))') result
  8  from test;

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ ----------
Something WW15 Target Complete WW15
WW12.3 Good to Go              WW12.3
What is that WW1.2             WW1.2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `WW[digits][dot][digits]` not surrounded by any characters except space (may be), you may use negative lookahead & lookbehind (lookarounds) like below.

```
with test (col) as
(
values 
  'SomethingWW15.3 WW12 Target Complete'
, 'WW12.3 Good to Go'
, 'WW12.3What is that WW1.2'
)
select 
  col
, regexp_substr(col, '(?<![^ ])WW[\d]+\.?[\d]?(?![^ ])') result
from test;

|COL                                 |RESULT|
|------------------------------------|------|
|SomethingWW15.3 WW12 Target Complete|WW12  |
|WW12.3 Good to Go                   |WW12.3|
|WW12.3What is that WW1.2            |WW1.2 |
```